# three.js - cannot read property "y" of undefined

Tags: three.js

thank you for your help, dumb newbie question…

Working with a proven example - after dragging a cube - getting this error when trying to log the position.y value of an item in an array.

At line 88:

```
console.log("position.y = " + this.objects.position.y);
```

I’ve tried many variants on this of course - thank you in advance

**EDIT (working link):**
https://codepen.io/ken-thomas/pen/rQayYg

Comment: Are you perhaps forgetting "new" when creating "position"? Like: var position = new THREE.Vector3 ()

Answer (score 0):

`this.objects` is an array of 200 or so meshes.

You need to pick which one you actually want to log the position of.

e.g:

```
this.objects[0].position.y
```

However, the `dragend` function gives you `event` data, one of the keys being the mesh you moved (event.object). So your code should look like this:

```
dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', (event) => {
    console.log('position.y = ', event.object.position.y);
});
```

Working codepen - https://codepen.io/danlong/pen/EOaRBw